# Android: Layout Files Margin/Padding Shortcuts

Tags: android, android-layout

hi do you know if there is a shortcut way to setup your layout files, a bit like CSS. e.g.
rather than

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

maybe like this?

```
android:layout_margin="20dp, 20dp, 10dp, 5dp"
```

the same would be for Padding/Radius etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want to set same value for all side then you can use like this:

```
android:layout_margin="20dp"
```

if you have different value for all side then you have to set them in this way:

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

and the same thing for padding.

Comment: it does look like this might be possible progrmatically. the xml is a bit silly in android I have to admit.